# MySQL - Set field values as values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I was wondering which would be the right query statement to take values from a table and insert them into another in a way similar to using the WHERE clause

Example -

Table1 contains fields:
registrynumber - name

Table2 contains fields:
id - firstname - lastname

The query must set Table1.name = Table2.firstname where Table1.registrynumber and Table2.id have the same values at the rows of Table1.name and Table2.firstname.

I hope i made it clear enough.
Regards.

Comment: Are you updating or inserting? That is not clear from your answer

Comment: The best way I can think of is to drop the name field from table1.  Part of database normalization is to store each piece of data only once.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Table2 tb2
SET tb2.firstname = ( SELECT name FROM Table1 WHERE registryname = tb2.id )
```

Comment: are you sure it will pick the right "tb2.id" which is in the same row of "tb2.firstname"

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (registrynumber, name)
SELECT id, firstname FROM Table2;
```